# copy first cell to second then add hours as int (DATEPART)

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, stored-procedures, datepart

I have data in the table like the following.

```
TimeIn                   TimeOut           
-------------------------------------
6/1/2010 09:00:00   Null     
6/2/2010 09:00:00   6/2/2010 16:45:00       
6/3/2010 10:05:00   Null                    
6/4/2010 07:30:00   6/4/2010 15:45:00
```

i have the stored procedure to find last activity with "not signd out" column

i have a stored procedure for copy a cell to other too ...

then, what i need,  is to update [TimeOut] (if there's no time out)

via more elegant way like

`UPDATE TimeOut SET DATEPART(HOUR, TimeOut) = DATEPART(HOUR, TimeIN) + 8`

so the Whole idea was to 
first check if last activity - Timeout Column is null

then if it is, sign TimeOut with max work hours allowed (8).

is there a simple way to do it ?

### UPDATE

as to marc answer , this is the selection of find out if user didn't sign out

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [TimeOut] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[TimeOut]) END FROM tblTime WHERE tId = ( SELECT MAX(tId) FROM tblTime WHERE UserId = 123
```

so i have the query that finds who did not sign out at last activity

then i only need to update that specific Row - field `TimeOut`

with hours of time in + 8 
that was my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should use `dateadd`.

```
UPDATE TimeOut 
SET TimeOut = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, TimeIN)
WHERE ....
```

This will set `TimeOut` to `TimeIn` plus eight hours.

Answer (score 0):

add a `where TimeOut IS NULL` clause so it updates only the ones where the field actually is null?

Comment: i did not understand you , i do have the part where i need to find if there's a user that did not "sign out" of work , then i need to update it's time out to TimeIn + 8 hours automatically (after i did acutally get to the information of that is the situation) and i do know that it's null

Comment: `update ... where timeout is null`, basically your query with the where clause added on.

Comment: yes, and that's what your query does. but you'd be updating ALL cells. adding the where clause will update only those that don't have a timeout.

Comment: So you actually meen that my Query is fine ? 
am i alllowed to use syntax like `SET DATEPART(HOUR,'OneField') = DATEPART(HOUR,'OtherField') +8 `

Comment: ok i know i know , sorry , i didn't talk about the global issue rather the specific part , i didn't even tried it . offcores i have a part that find select MAX(tid) from tblTime WHERE TIMEOUT is null (somthing more complicatad with case and stuff , i will post this too now

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblTime  SET TimeOut = DATEADD(HOUR,8,TimeIn) WHERE tId = ( SELECT MAX(tId) FROM tblTime WHERE UserId = 1234)
```